# pytest caplog empty when tests run on package

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, caplog

I am writing unit tests for a method that generate logs. I used pytest's `caplog` to check the log output, and while it works when I run on module like: `pytest module_name.py`, it fails when I run pytest on package `pytest tests` and `caplog` is empty.
Note that `logger.propagate` is set to `True`

Below my test method:

```py
def test_correctly_mark_email_as_seen(mocker, caplog):
    mailbox = mocker.MagicMock()
    message = mocker.MagicMock()
    caplog.set_level(logging.INFO)
    mark_email_as_seen(mailbox, message)
    assert '::mark_email_as_seen, email marked as seen' in caplog.text
```

And the failure message:

```
>       assert '::mark_email_as_seen, email marked as seen' in caplog.text
E       AssertionError: assert '::mark_email_as_seen, email marked as seen' in ''
E        +  where '' = <_pytest.logging.LogCaptureFixture object at 0x10c88f580>.text

tests/test_email.py:12: AssertionError
```

My other tests are working just fine running them either on package or module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was specifying the logger level in one of the test files where I didn't need logs, and apparently `pytest` takes that into consideration when it's running on a folder, so the logs didn't show for any test file which caused this problem.

Comment: can you elaborate on this how did you fix it ? I am facing the same problem , caplog only have logs on the file level not on folder level

Comment: @Niladri it's been a while since I've had this problem, but as I said in my comment when you set the log level in any given test file and run tests on the whole folder, it will take the lowest (highest?) log level.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify logger name, when you set the level.

```
caplog.set_level(logging.INFO, logger="YOUR_LOGGER_NAME")
```

Comment: I did try that but got the same empty log.

Comment: Did you try to use root logger in mark_email_as_seen() just to check how it works with root?
I met this issue in my tests too, but was resolved by propagate=1(True) for package logger. I see that you have done it already.